# How to get the same capability of DataFrame 'query' method in older pandas version?

Tags: pandas

I need to dynamically query a dataframe with an amount of criteria that will only be available at runtime. I noticed pandas 0.13 will have a query method but I can't upgrade yet. Is there a way to achieve the same thing in pandas 0.12?

At the moment I am just iterating over a list of criteria and applying them one by one...

Comment: Perhaps you can use numexpr on the values...

Comment: Thank @AndyHayden, I am not sure what you are referring to could you please refer me to some example/documentation?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/